# Sum Sql is not working as expected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a view that has values with total on each row plus the date.
I want to sum all the total for each date

- V_stock
- cd_client
- qty
- dt

v_stock_sum

```
select sum(qty), dt
from v_stock
group by (dt)
```

This gives a ridiculous number, what am i doing wrong, any tip helps thanks

V_stock

```
cd_client   qty              dt
LIMA        3360             2017-02-20
```

v_stock_sum

```
qty     dt
 120960 2017-02-20
```

I expected since there is one line only 3360

Comment: You will need to provide sample data and desired results.  The query looks fine.

Comment: It may depend on data types. I reproduced with test table (id serial, name varchar(30), qty numeric(10,3), dt date) and your example with 1 line works correct, so please provide all missing information

Answer (score 0):

probably you have some problems with your view:

try to run count also to check if your view return more then one row

```
select sum(qty),
       count(*) as rows,
       dt
from v_stock
group by dt
```

if you will get more then 1 in the count then you need to check why you got more then one row

also you didn't put any condition on the cd_client
maybe you have only one row for each cd_client